# Holders.grailsApplication.config is null when deploying to tomcat

Tags: grails

I'm running grails 2.2.4.  The following code works fine in development.  When I deploy the war file to tomcat an exception is thrown that grailsApplication.config is null:

```
import grails.util.Holders

public enum PhotoSize {

    PROFILE(Holders.grailsApplication.config.img.profile.height, Holders.grailsApplication.config.img.profile.width),
    SEARCH_RESULT(Holders.grailsApplication.config.img.search.height, Holders.grailsApplication.config.img.search.width),
    GALLERY(Holders.grailsApplication.config.img.gallery.full.height, Holders.grailsApplication.config.img.gallery.full.width),
    GALLERY_THUMBNAIL(Holders.grailsApplication.config.img.gallery.thumbnail.height, Holders.grailsApplication.config.img.gallery.thumbnail.width),
    MEMBER_THUMBNAIL(Holders.grailsApplication.config.img.member.thumbnail.height, Holders.grailsApplication.config.img.member.thumbnail.width)

    //def config = Holders.config


     //def grailsApplication
...
```

I'm trying to set some enum values by loading them from Config.groovy.  A workaround is to just hard code the values since they aren't likely to change.  However I am curious as to why the config file would be null.  Also is it not possible to inject grailsApplication into an enum?

I'm calling Holders.grailsApplication.  Injecting grailsApplication doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Have you tried using `Holders.config.img.profile.height` (the config object directly instead of referring to grailsApplication)? I suppose you would not face this issue if you do so.

Answer (score 3):

The constructor calls to create enum values will happen as part of the static initialization of the enum type.  If this occurs before the GrailsApplication has been bootstrapped then you'll get null.  In development mode the config is loaded much earlier in the start up process than it is when running as a WAR (as it needs to be available to the command line scripts).

It may be better to approach the problem differently, for example have a service method or taglib that takes the enum type as a parameter and returns the appropriate dimension extracted from the config.

Comment: Exactly. I was going to suggest `Hodlers.config` instead of `Holders.grailsApplication` since the config object is loaded by the context class loader. So we need not worry about instantiating the `grailsApplication` bean for this operation?

Comment: Holders.config over Holders.grailsApplication worked in my scenario where I was trying to access some config values from a static method.

Comment: @whitespy9 for some static methods that may work, it's all down to exactly when in the startup process the method in question gets _called_.